# Js Form Validation error disappear

Tags: magento-1.9, form-validation, prototype-js

I've this really strange issue with form js validation error.

I've never edited anything related to it and there are no js errors in the console.

The problem is that an error like "This is a required field" appear for 1 - 2 seconds and then disappear.

Looking the console I can see that the opacity of the div .validation-advice goes from 0 to 1 and the again from 1 to 0 without stopping.

And also the display property remains "none".

This happens in every situation where js validation is required.

This is a screenshot of login page

[image]

I'm going crazy I really don't know where to check.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a newsletter validation where I had two required fields. When one of these fields were filled out correctly, I'd get your problem. The problem was that the input fields had the same IDs, "newsletter". By changing one of the two ID's to "newsletter-name", the problem was fixed. Make sure that the IDs on the input fields are unique.